# Intercepting keyboard presses

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an input box that always has focus.  The commands that go into this input box are always letters.  If the user presses a number, I would like it not to be added to the text box, but instead use it to run a different command (just like a hotkey).

The way I've seen this implemented is by looking at the `keyup` event and removing unwanted characters.  Instead, is there any way to to intercept the keyboard input and check what the value is before the insert?

I've thought about creating a custom input field using a div and intercepting all the keyboard commands.  Is there a way to get a blinking caret so that it looks like an input box?

Comment: google "css cursor w3schools"

Comment: @thatidiotguy google "w3fools" ;)

Comment: @jbabey I don't see the harm for giving him a good tutorial on how to use the cursor CSS2 property. The actual w3 specifications do not look as friendly.

Comment: @thatidiotguy most people prefer official (and correct) [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/cursor), though i'm not sure how CSS cursor is relevant to this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you want a `contenteditable` div:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

You can listen for `keydown` events and prevent them if they aren't letters:

```
$("#editor").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which > 90 || (e.which > 48 && e.which < 65)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

To process the numbers as "hotkeys" you would just determine which key `e.which` is and act accordingly.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/g3mgR/1

Answer (score 3):

Something like this will work:

```
<input type="text" id="txt" />​
```

For jQuery:

```
$('#txt').keydown(function (e) {
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    if (key > 46 && key < 58) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('its a number, do something');
    }
});​
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gWZf6/3/)

Comment: The fiddle has a typo in the if condition: `||` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `keydown` instead of `keyup`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `keypress` event in combination with `String.fromCharCode`:

```
document.getElementById('yourTextBoxID').onkeypress = function () {
    var characterPressed = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);

    if (characterPressed.test(/[a-z]/i)) {
        // user pressed a letter
    } else {
        // user did not press a letter
    }
};​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TSB9r/3/